# How to show pop using Angular 2 using below code?

Tags: angular

I want to show pop using Angular 2. I want to change below code to Angular 2.

```
$('#myModal').modal(show)
```

I tried below code using another way in Bootstrap it works

```
<button (click)="moveMultipleFolder()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moveModel"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" ></i>Move</button>
```

but I want to show pop when we click copyMultipleFolder().

so my current code is :

```
<button (click)="copyMultipleFolder()"></i>Copy</button>
//pop up
<div class="modal fade" id="copyModel" role="dialog" [hiden]="model">

component :
@private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;

 @ViewChild('copyModel') selectFromElRef;
copyMultipleFolder(){

}
```

but I don't what to do in copyMultipleFolder(){} function to enable popup.

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service; please do some research and show your attempts to implement this in Angular 2.

Comment: yes . i did .. i tried using     below code and it works .        <li><button (click)="moveMultipleFolder()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moveModel"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" ></i>Move</button></li>

Comment: Then please [edit] the question to give a [mcve].

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.* Please include your expected results, your attempted solutions, and why they didn't work. Please see the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) for more details.

Comment: hey i have updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML on `div` `#myModal` you append directive `<div id="myModal" [hidden]="modal">`...

In component, you just manipulate with `modal` which is a boolean variable. It just indicates whether the modal should be open or not.

Comment: ..."u" -> "you"

Answer (score 0):

Check out ng2-bootstrap to open modals in angular2 applications: http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/modals

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer